# Xamarin.Android Hide Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-navigation-bar

I tried so many ways to hide the navigation bar but nothing works

```cs
SystemUiFlags flags = SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation
    | SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)flags;
```

This e.g. doesn't work, even though it should.

I am using Xamarin.Android, so anything Xamarin.Forms related doesn't work asaik

What Parameter, Flag or Option do I have to call/set to hide the Navigation Bar?

In the [Xamarin.Android Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/navigation-bar) is shown how to hide it, but it is deprecated. No wonder if it is from 2017...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below method:

```
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation | (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesnt work. You can check [here (gitea repo)](https://gitea.kaaaxcreators.de/kaaax0815/AsyncWeather.Xamarin/src/commit/83a465c2485c0a4fe396581f81c89dea3ba46dc6/SplashScreen.cs), I am using the Android Emulator, but this shouldnt make difference